# How can I fix mongoose nested sort problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have 2 model

User

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
}, {
  collection: 'users',
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
})
mongoose.model('Users', schema)
```

Channel

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Users',
    alias: 'user'
  }
}, {
  collection: 'channels',
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
})
mongoose.model('Channels', schema)
```

Example Query

```
Channels.find().populate('user_id').sort({ 'user_id.updated_at': -1 })
```

I want to populate user model and sorting by `user.updated_at`. but not working(not sorting). How can I fix this. I dont want to aggregate.

Comment: Clarify your question, and explain "not working". Show debugging details

Comment: @LinDu very simple, 'not sorting'

Comment: Why don't you want aggregate?

Comment: @ErdemÜn Lin Du's comment actually make sense. "not sorting" is not clear enough. What level of sorting you are expecting? document level? the array entries in `user_id`? If you provide sample documents and expected output, we can take closer look.

Comment: @ErdemÜn  shouldn't you be using "user.updated_at" instead of "user_id.updated_at" ?